# onNext no observer nunca é chamado

Tags: rxjava

Considere o seguinte trecho de código.

```
ReplaySubject<List<Object>> subject = ReplaySubject.create();

subject.subscribe(view::mostraListaObjetos);

subject.onNext(getListOnline());
//logo apos essa linha o metodo view.mostrarListaObjetos(lista)
//deveria ser chamado ou estou errado?
```

O problema é que não importa quantas vezes eu chame o onNext() o observer nunca recebe nada.
alguém ae tem a ideia do porquê?

**Editado** havia resumido o codigo, porem descobri que dessa forma funciona bem, porem quando uso os operadores `flatMapInterable`e `toList` é que não recebo nada até que o `subject.onComplete()` é chamado!

Exemplo do codigo detalhado.

```
ReplaySubject<List<Object>> subject = ReplaySubject.create();
subject.flatMapIterable(object -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "flatMapIterable: it is called");
            return object;
        }).doOnEach(objNotification -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnEach: it is called"))
          .toList()
          .subscribe(obj -> Log.d(TAG, "subscribe: it is only called after subscribe.onComplete()"));
subject.onNext(getListOfObjects());
Log.d(TAG, "onComplete:");
subject.onComplete();
```

Saida do logcat:

```
07-04 23:20:38.258 10770-10770/app.package D/TAG: flatMapIterable: it is called
07-04 23:20:38.259 10770-10770/app.package D/TAG: doOnEach: it is called
07-04 23:20:38.259 10770-10770/app.package D/TAG: onComplete:
07-04 23:20:38.260 10770-10770/app.package D/TAG: doOnEach: it is called
07-04 23:20:38.260 10770-10770/app.package D/TAG: it is only called after subscribe.onComplete()
```

Comment: Na [doc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html#onNext(T)) diz que sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este é o comportamento padrão do operador toList(), e que causa [alguma confusão](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3861). Como explicado no [Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList--), ele precisa que o *upstream* sinalize o `onComplete` para emitir a lista.

No diagrama também é possível ver este comportamento, já que a seta só sai do operador `toList` depois do `onComplete` do *upstream*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Muito Obrigado Leonardo!